# What is/are the meaning(s) of 方便 in this sentence and in general?

Tags: meaning, nuances, anime

I was reviewing some old cards I had flagged as "uncertain" and I came across a scene from "Your name" (君の名は).

At around the 47th minute the characters ride a shinkansen to meet the "friend" of the MC.

The dialogue is as follows:

> Colleague : たきくん、メル友に会いに行くんだって。
>
> Taki： いや、メル友っていうかそりゃ方便で…

From my understanding it can mean something like "Just a figure of speech"
The definitions of J to J dictionaries are not very helpful either.

> （１）ある目的を達するため便宜的に用いられる手段。てだて。「うそも―」
>
> （２）〔仏〕
> 〔梵 upāya〕
> （ア）仏が衆生(シユジヨウ)を教化・救済するために用いるさまざまな方法。（イ）真実の教えに至る前段階として教化される側の，宗教的能力に応じて説かれた教え。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first definition says "a means employed expediently to attain an objective." 嘘も方便 is a fixed expression that means telling a lie is sometimes necessary to achieve a greater goal, or something like that. Outside of this expression, 方便 is often used in the sense of "pretext" or "ostensible reason."

The character is suggesting meeting their e-pal is not the real purpose of their trip.